# HTML5で画像を回転させると縁にジャギが出てしまう

Tags: javascript, css, html5

HTML5で画像を回転させて表示させると、斜めになった画像の縁の部分がギザギザになってしまいます。このジャギを回避する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: どのように画像を回転させているのかを詳しく教えていただければありがたいです。お願いします

Comment: 回転はCSS3のtransform: rotate();プロパティでしょうか?

Comment: CSS3のtransform: rotate();プロパティや、JavaScriptのCanvas 2D Context の rotate() を使って、画像を微妙に（例えば5度程度）回転した際にジャギが目立ちました。

Comment: @SotaYamashita   jqueryっぽく回転する実装[http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/290/jquery%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%A6%81%E7%B4%A0%E3%82%92%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2]

Comment: 具体的にどのように画像を回転させているか明示した方が良いと思います。また、どのようにギザギザになっているか、可能であれば画像をアップした方が回答者の助けになると思います。

Comment: 問題が発生してるソースコードや、ご確認されたブラウザのバージョンなどを教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 7):

imgへの`transform: rotate();`の適用でもcanvasでもそうなのですが、どちらもベクターではなくピクセル操作になるので、計算上端数が出るとジャギが見えると思いますし、ディスプレイのppiでも影響するので完全なコントロールは難しいかもしれませんね。  
前述の制約があるとして、その中で工夫するのであれば

- borderを使ってnピクセルぶんの縁を作ってベクターラインで囲む
- `box-shadow`を使ってドロップシャドウを生成してジャギが目立つ部分側に適用する
- 表示するサイズの2倍のイメージを用意して、サイズ指定で50%表示で使うことでサンプリング数をあげる

あたりを組み合わせて試してみると良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

画像を上下左右1ピクセル大きくして、1ピクセル幅の透明の縁をつけると、回転してもジャギらなくなります。

Comment: その場合のソースコードを教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

ジャギの出るのはどのブラウザでもでしょうか？
Firefoxであれば下記が参考になるかと思います。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox

```css
body {
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
}

div {
  -moz-transform: rotateX(45deg);
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; width:10em; height:10em; background:hotpink;margin-left:8em;"></div>
```