# jQueryを拡張して要素を回転させたい

Tags: javascript, html5, jquery

jQueryっぽく要素を回転させたい

```
$("#elem").rotate(90);　=> #elemが90度回転
$("#elem").rotate() => "90"が返る
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

こんな感じになります。

```
$.fn.rotate = function( deg ) {
  if( deg === undefined ) {
    deg = $(this[0]).data.rotateDeg;
    if ( deg === undefined ) { return 0; }
    else { return deg; }
  }

  this.each(function(){         
    var $el = $(this);
    var rotation = 'rotate('+ (deg) +'deg)';
    $el
      .css({ 
       'webkitTransform': rotation ,
       'mozTransform' : rotation ,
       'msTransform' : rotation ,
       'oTransform' : rotation ,
       'transform' : rotation });
      $el.data.rotateDeg = deg;
    });
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery 1.8以降ならベンダプレフィックスは自動付加なのでこうでしょうか。

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.rotate = function(angle) {
    if(angle == null) {
      return this.data("angle") || 0;
    } else {
      return this.data("angle", angle)
        .css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```